# Need to use python from an external hard drive

Tags: python, opencv

I want to be able to plug in an external hard drive on my computer and use the installed python on it to run my programs. So would I start cmd and cd to the new hard drive? When I installed python I installed it onto the hard drive. I just need to know how I would install new packages and make sure the files I have know the correct path. For example on the hard drive I have a program that runs a webcam with Opencv but I don’t have that installed on the hard drive version of python. So how would I install modules and make sure my programs on it use the correct path to use them?

Comment: Just provide the path to python/pip executable when running anything, so the system doesn't use python from PATH. E.g. pip will be `/external/location/python3 -m pip install package_name` or `/external/location/pip3 install package_name` , and running your script would be `/external/location/python3 filename` (without .py)

Answer (score 0):

You will want a portable version of python. I myself use [WinPython](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/) for this.
It lets you open a cmd window within the portable context and then you can pip install and do whatever you would normally do but it wont pollute the current OS